# Can I use action variants to show/hide content from different devices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I understand if I do not state the variant, what will be shown is the default template.

However, if I only wanted to show something through the mobile device and NOT the desktop, is it possible to hide it from the desktop viewer, i.e. remove the default view for the desktop viewer so they can't even access the same content as the mobile user?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at mobvious: https://github.com/jistr/mobvious-rails

In your view:

```
<% for_device_type :mobile do %>
   <%= render 'mobile_partial' %>
<% end %>
<% for_device_type :tablet, :desktop do %>
   <%= render 'partial' %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller:

```
for_device_type :mobile do
  render 'edit_mobile', layout: 'mobile'
end
for_device_type :tablet, :desktop do
  render 'edit'
end
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this -- my only concern is that it hasn't been updated in 3 years so might not work well with the latest version of rails.